# 'OpenGL/OpenGL.h' file not found in xcode10

Tags: opengl-es, gpuimage, xcode10

I just downloaded Xcode10 and built my project for the first time and I'm getting 'OpenGL/OpenGL.h' file not found in xcode10 for one of the libraries I'm importing (GPUImage).

The error is occurring here:

```
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

This was working fine in Xcode 9. Does this have to do with OpenGL ES being deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

It was an issue with GPUImage, have to remove the complete contents of framework/Source/Mac/ and remove GPUImageMac.xcodeproj and then the error disappears.